# Robots.txt Query String - Couldn't Disallow

Tags: robots.txt

I have url : http://www.website.com/shopping/books/?b=9

I disallowed `/?b=9` from robots.txt

as

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?b=9
```

But when i test this from Google Webmaster, on Robots.txt Test Tools, it Shows this page allowed while it should not...

Please tell any wrong with my robots.txt

---

Also

URL - http://www.website.com/shopping/books/?b=9

there `/?b=9` this will be same in all cases and `/shopping/books/` will be change with different category.

How to Block this types of string ?

```
Disallow: /?b=9
```

Is it correct ?